# How to type an array of objects with certain keys in each position?

Tags: typescript

I want to type this array:

```
const arrayToType=[{index:3,value:'foo'}, {amout:4},{total:45, extra:'foo'}]
```

I know all my arrays will have those keys in those positions in the arrays, the only thing that will change will be the values of each key, not the types.

how can I type a fixed array of objects structure like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done simply by declaring a `type` for a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/tuples)

```
type ArrayType = [{index: number, value: string}, {amout: number}, {total: number, extra: string}];
const arrayToType: ArrayType=[{index:3,value:'foo'}, {amout:4},{total:45, extra:'foo'}]
```

This *does* require that your array has 3 elements and that they match positionally. There may be other quirks, but this would be the basis to start with.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAKuaBeKBtA3gSwDsATCADwC4pCBXAWwCMI4AaKAN0QBsaIqBnYHCIBzAL5tciOgHsawKrUbMJUXMBnBui+k1ZRyQxAKGixAXQDcAWABQAYxmFBURAmQoZaSFXhJU6Bh4RKSUAMwsnDx8AOQAZjIyMapSsvIUACwS6praGQCsbIZIFPGJyeZ2QA)

The way tuples work, you can add *more* to the end, but those values are not strongly typed. Check out [Rest Elements in Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#example/rest-elements-in-tuple-types) for some more details.

Comment: That's perfect!. Could you tell me how can I manage if I wanted to constraint at least the first three objects, but I wanted to give freedom to accept the rest of the objects without any constraint?

Comment: @pepinillo6969 Added additional comment and link to "rest elements".

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution with dynamic type

```
interface MyType {
      [key: string]: string | number | undefined;
    }
    interface MyTypes extends Array<MyType> {}
    
    var arrayToType: MyTypes = [
      { index: 3, value: "foo" },
      { amout: 4 },
      { total: 45, extra: "foo" },
    ];
```

Comment: No...in this case what is wanted is to constraint the type of objects to certain objects in certain fixed positions in the array. This solution wouldn't have this constraint because you could make an array of any key/value objects that typescript wouldn't complain.